# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. Could not connect to the Gradle daemon

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on M2101K6P in debug mode...

main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:

Could not connect to the Gradle daemon. Daemon uid: 645aa93d-5f53-4a0f-9024-2ad863c6db88 with diagnostics:

Daemon pid: 6424

I get this error even while running the default flutter application template in vscode & same in Android studio. Im seriously stuck at this for couple of days and hoping to find a fix :)